# relationship between the structure of a finite abelian group and its subgroup structure if any?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be a finite abelian group. Then by structure theorem 
$G=Z_{n_1}×Z_{n_2}×Z_{n_3}×...×Z_{n_s}$

where $s\ge 1,n_{i+1}|n_i$ for $1\le i \le s-1$

Now let $H\le G$,again by the structure theorem

$H=Z_{m_1}×Z_{m_2}×Z_{m_3}×...×Z_{m_t} $

where $t\ge 1,m_{i+1}|m_i$ for $1\le i \le t-1$

My question is whether there is some sort of relationship between the structures of $H$ and $G$ ? I mean $t\le s$ and as such..

My intuition says yes though I am unable to proceed in any direction . I am also aware of the fact that subgroups of direct product may not be direct product of subgroups. Does it have some implication in this question ?.I have looked everywhere but in vain.

It will be very helpful if one can give me a proof or at least a sketch of proof with a bit of theoretical discussion since I am mostly self-studying.

Thanks and regard to you !!

Comment: It is easier to get the structure of subgroups using the primary divisor decomposition rather than the invariant factor one. Yes, there is a relation, but with the primary division decomposition it is much easier to state.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin..Thanks for your response ,sir. As you said, I  know about primary divisor decomposition form and obtaining it from invariant factor form.If I have the required form for $G$, then what is the exact relation between.the structures? Please give the proof, if possible.

Comment: Should this be posted as a separate question?

Comment: If $G=C_{p^{a_1}}\oplus\cdots\oplus C_{p^{a_m}}$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, $1\leq a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_m$, then the subgroups are the groups of the form $H\cong C_{p^{b_1}}\oplus\cdots\oplus C_{p^{b_m}}$, with $0\leq b_i\leq a_i$, $b_1\leq b_2\leq\cdots\leq b_n$. You should try to prove it yourself. You can do this for every $p$-part of $G$ separately.